# an EditText placed inside a drawer layout is not responding to touches

Tags: android

When I try click the edittext nothing happens (The keyboard and cursor don't  appear). The isInEditMode() method is returning false. The isFocused() method also returns false.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/LightGrey">

       <EditText
        android:id="@+id/essay_edit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="start|left"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:background="@color/LightGrey"
        android:maxLines="500"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        android:typeface="serif" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start">

        <include
            layout="@layout/drawer_layout" />

    </FrameLayout>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the `EditText` outside of the `DrawerLayout`:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">



    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/essay_edit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="start|left"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:background="@color/LightGrey"
        android:maxLines="500"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start">

        <include
            layout="@layout/drawer_layout" />

    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: I moved the edit text to outside the drawerLayout and the edit text works fine, but now swiping right from the left edge no longer opens the navigation menu

Comment: @bigDaddy where is your navigationView ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use irrelevant framelayout only for edit text

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/essay_edit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="start|left"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:background="@color/LightGrey"
        android:maxLines="500"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start">

        <include
            layout="@layout/drawer_layout" />

    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```